# Dynamic GridView with all Formatting and template fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add gridview dynamically with all formatting and with template fields ..

i m trying it by below way.

```
public StringBuilder getTextForGridView()
{
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(" <asp:GridView ID=\"GridView1\" runat=\"server\" AutoGenerateColumns=\"False\" ");
sb.AppendLine(" CellPadding=\"4\" ForeColor=\"#333333\" GridLines=\"None\" ShowHeader=\"true\">");

sb.AppendLine(" <Columns>");

sb.AppendLine(" <asp:TemplateField>");
sb.AppendLine(" <HeaderTemplate>");

sb.AppendLine(" <asp:Label ID=\"lbl1\" runat=\"server\" Text='<%#Eval(\"Id\")%>'></asp:Label>");
sb.AppendLine(" </HeaderTemplate>");
sb.AppendLine(" <ItemTemplate>");
sb.AppendLine(" <asp:Label ID=\"lbl1\" runat=\"server\" Text='<%#Eval(\"Id\")%>'></asp:Label>");

sb.AppendLine(" </ItemTemplate>");

sb.AppendLine(" </asp:TemplateField>");

sb.AppendLine(" <asp:TemplateField>");
sb.AppendLine(" <HeaderTemplate>");

sb.AppendLine(" <asp:Label ID=\"lbl1\" runat=\"server\" Text='<%#Eval(\"Name\")%>'></asp:Label>");
sb.AppendLine(" </HeaderTemplate>");
sb.AppendLine(" <ItemTemplate>");
sb.AppendLine(" <asp:Label ID=\"lbl1\" runat=\"server\" Text='<%#Eval(\"Name\")%>'></asp:Label>");

sb.AppendLine(" </ItemTemplate>");

sb.AppendLine(" </asp:TemplateField>");
sb.AppendLine(" </Columns>");

sb.AppendLine(" </asp:GridView>");

return sb;
}
```

then i m assigning below text to literal as and adding it to placeholder

```
Literal li = new Literal();
li.ID = "lit";
li.Text = getTextForGridView().ToString();

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(li);
```

but the problem is i m not able to assign datasource to gridview as i m not able to get object of gridview..
Please get me out of here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a string to the page, you have to add a GridView instance to the ControlTree in order for ASP.NET to know about it.  Take a look at this article to get a better understanding.

[Dynamic Controls in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131055/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Rick said, you can add a new GridView to the ControlTree programmatically:

```
GridView myGV = New GridView();
myGV.ID = "GridView1";
myGV.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
...
```

You can let your columns autogenerate (with the GridView.AutoGenerateColumns property) or manually add DataControlFields to the Columns collection:

```
BoundField col1 = New BoundField();
col1.HeaderText = "Column Header Text";
col1.DataField = "DataSourceColumn";
myGV.Columns.Add(bField);
```

See the [Gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) and [DataControlField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.aspx) MSDN articles for details.